# Windows Phone SDK Network

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone

I am getting used to the Windows Phone SDK in Visual Studio.

Right now I am writing a simple web browser so that I can build off of it in the future in C#.

**What I am having an issue with** is - if the phone doesn't have any signal:

- I don't want the application to redirect to the generic could not find the website that you are looking for.
- I would like it to redirect to a new page that I have control over.

So **my basic question** is this - is there a way to detect whether the phone has a connection to the network - or better yet if the phone redirects to a new website?

I need that because I could potentially catch the error and display something like you aren't connected to a network please try again once you have connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can find whether your phone is connected with network or not in windows phone
try this 
add a name space `using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;`

```
if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable)
{
MessageBox.Show("Network");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("No Network");
}
```

Comment: Alright this looks like exactly what I need. I put my computer into airplane mode to remove the internet. The problem is Devicenetworkinformation.IsnetworkAvailable seems to always return true and run the browser.navigate(uri). Does the emulator not know that it doesn't have network?

Comment: @TokerFloyd emulator uses system's network that's why emulator always connect with internet.